# Alpine execute command in a new shell

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, alpine-linux

I'm using an Alpine image in docker and I wanted to know if there is a command to open a new terminal and execute a command.

Like :

```
gnome-terminal -e <command>
```

I've already searched in ash man but didn't find what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You always have a choice of running commands on running containers irrespective of the OS type.

```
docker image pull nginx
docker container run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 nginx
docker exec -ti nginx sh -c "echo 'Hello World'"
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to do it in a Dockerfile with RUN